# How to prove this identity about Sylvestered partitions of n into m parts such that ...

Tags: sequences-and-series, integer-partitions

Let us say a partition $\lambda$ is $Sylvestered$ if the smallest part to appear an even number of times ($0$ is an even number) is even. For each set of positive integers $T$, define $S(T\,;m,\,n)$ as the number of Sylvestered partitions of n into m parts such that no elements of $T$ are repeated. Then

$$\sum_{m;n \geq 0}S(T\, ; m,n)x^m q^n=\frac{\prod_{k\in T}(1-x^2 q^{2k})}{\prod_{j=1}^\infty (1-x q^j)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1}q^{n(2n-1)}}{(-xq)_{2n}}$$,

and $(-xq)_{2n}=(1+xq)(1+xq^2) \cdots (1+xq^{2n})$.

Comment: I suppose you're asking for a proof? If so maybe mention that, since as it is this is not a question. Is the formula at the bottom just the definition of $(-xq)_{2n},$ which goes in the displayed formula after the sum? I'd also appreciate some concrete examples of Sylvestered vs not Sylvestered partitions $\lambda$.

Comment: The bottom is just the definition of $(-x q)_{2 n}$, unfortunately,  I cannot figure out the properties Sylvestered partitions have.

Comment: Without knowing what they look like, it would be impossible to get such a generating function. Any luck via google of "Sylvestered Partition"??

Comment: Lincoln: I think at least a link to where you got this formula might make it possible for someone to follow it up and see exactly what is being counted. For example if we partition $6$ into $3$ parts say as $1+1+4$, what does the phrase "no elements of $T$ are repeated" mean? Does it mean for this example that $1 \not\in T$?